# Phonegap/Cordova to achieve Youtube/Facebook app layout with fixed Header and slide in main content

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to achieve the youtube/facebook app layout for phonegap/JQM. Their Header is fixed through out different pages. But the main content slide in from left or right.

In Jquery Mobile/Phonegap, the only method is to have the header fixed in different pages, then to use CSS3 for the main content to slide in, this is the only method i can think of, not sure if JQM has other layout like that.

Answer (score 0):

In JQM place the fixed header outside the data-page="role". so when you navigate between pages (slide, pop etc...) it animates smoothly.

Comment: Place it outside data-role"page"?? But then it won't show up at all. Because 1 page has to be shown at a time right?

Comment: It will show up. Use position:fixed;top: 0px;z-index:1000 for header and it should.